# HereMaps iOS SDK v4.13.3 not compiling with Xcode 14.3

Tags: here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

Seeing two errors:

`.../Sources/HereMaps/AnnotationState.swift:2:8 Failed to build module 'heresdk'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.8 (swiftlang-5.8.0.117.11 clang-1403.0.22.8.60)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.`

As well as a number of errors in the swiftinterface:

`@objc @_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @IBDesignable @_Concurrency.MainActor(unsafe) open class MapView : UIKit.UIView, heresdk.MapViewBase {`

`/path/to/DerivedData/heresdk.framework/Modules/heresdk.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:5702:69 'MainActor' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer`

Application is using MainActor features, but it does not appear as though it has set iOS 13.0 minimums.

Comment: SDK version 4.12.4 seems to work fine, so the change was somewhere between 4.12.4 and 4.13.3

Comment: Newer versions of the HERE SDK are also affected?

Answer (score 1):

With the Xcode 14.3 RC2 the error is gone.